# Microsoft WebSocket APIs

Tags: winapi, websocket

I am using the Microsoft WebSocket APIs (such as [**WinHttpWebSocketReceive**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707328.aspx)). I am using them in Synchronous mode and observe that the call to **WinHttpWebSocketReceive** blocks when there is no data available.

What is the expected design pattern for calling these functions? My incoming *"message"* has a defined size, but there doesn't seem to be a way to access the size and hence set that size in the call to **WinHttpWebSocketReceive**. I can see received data in the buffer when debugging although the function has not returned.

My Socket server (an LG TV) sends messages unsolicited (i.e. not in response to sent message) so I need to wait and watch for them. At the moment I am doing this by issuing a [**WinHttpWebSocketSend**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707329.aspx) with an empty string which tends to generate an invalid parameter message.

I have tried in asynchronous mode but find the memory model too complex with my outbound messages seeming to become corrupted. Again I haven't found a documented example of this.

Comment: Did you study the sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/WinhttpWebsocket/cpp/WinhttpWebsocket.cpp)?

Comment: Yes - it's a linear request response in the use case I am dealing with responses may arrive unsolicited 
Thanks
Mark